# How to update gt p1000 system 2.2 in 2016?

Tags: root-access, updates, 2.3-gingerbread

I got an old Gt P1000 Galaxy and I have been studying Android stuff first time in my life. I have watched youtube videos about updating 2.2 system to new ones but the thing is that nothing supports the machine anymore. I cannot root the thing or do any preparations that updating needs. Any ideas what should I do? I don't undestand why the previous owner didn't update even Gingerbread in it when it was still possible. Is there something I can do or the equipment ready for recycling bin?

Comment: Did you read this yet? http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2681282

Answer (score 0):

As long as [SamMobile](http://www.sammobile.com/firmwares/database/GT-P1000/) and [XDA-Developers](http://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-tab/development) still exist, you will not toss that thing into the recycling bin without a try.

Start from updating the thing to official Gingerbread firmware available for download from SM (download page also offers tools and a brief guide), then install custom recovery and flash whatever you want from there. If you don't mind the lag you could even install CM13 (Android 6.0.x) for some fun.